# Why doesn't Synaptic start?

Tags: synaptic

When I start synaptic package manager normally (Super-Synaptic), it asks for a password. When I enter password, nothing happens!

When I start synaptic form terminal using `synaptic-pkexec`, I get:

```
No protocol specified

** (synaptic:2760): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified

(synaptic:2760): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

And I am back to the prompt.

When I start synaptic form terminal using `sudo synaptic`, it asks for sudo password in the terminal on entering it, it gives:

```
(synaptic:2721): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/..../ibus/bus is not root!
```

Then several messages like:

```
(synaptic:2842): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkNotebook 0x84c1128 is mapped but visible child GtkLabel 0x8693970 is not mapped
```

And synaptic starts with administrative privileges.

What is happening? How do I get the normal behaviour (Super-synaptics-password) sequence back?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had issue like this, but I stumbled upon a forum which said to try these;

```
grep 'pam_xauth.so' /etc/pam.d/*  | awk -F ":" '{ printf "%s\t(%s)\n", $2, $1}'
```

if that didn't work then you just set this into **/etc/sudoers**

```
Defaults env_keep=DISPLAY
```

logout and back in again and it should work.